# Unable to Start Hive Action from Second Run of Oozie Workflow Job

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

Am facing bit issue while running Hive Action from Oozie from Second Workflow Job Run.
On the 1st Run of the Worfklow Jobs is running fine with Pig & Hive Action , but whenever the Job is going to run on its second instance, on scheduled time the same job getting failed with Hive exception saying not able to access the metastore derby. {not Sure which Jar the same is checking for Derby, where am using Oracle and same is updated in hive-site.xml, hive-default.xml}

If the job started freshly after killing the previous instance the same is getting completed as expected.

Using Hive0.9 and Oozie 3.3.0, metastore using Oracle
Have updated the hive-site.xml,hive-default.xml, oozie-user-hive-default.xml in HDFS along with in Local and Shared Location of DFS Oozie, but still the same not working.

My work flow as below :

```
<action name="hiveForUploadData">
<hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
<value>default</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
<value>${namenode}/user/hive-default/hive-default.xml</value> -- {have tried with hive-site.xml & oozie-user-hive-default.xml as well }
</property>
</configuration>
<script>UploadScripts.q</script>
<param>inputfile_name=/user/input/table/filename</param>
</hive>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="error"/>
</action>
<kill name="error">
<message>Hive Action Failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
```

1st Run got success, working fine Oracle Meta Store getting updated as well
2nd run Getting failed with : not able to access metastore {derby}
1836 [main] INFO  hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver  - Parse Completed
1959 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore  - 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
1985 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore  - ObjectStore, initialize called
2278 [main] ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin  - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.resources" but it cannot be resolved.
2278 [main] ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin  - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved.
2278 [main] ERROR DataNucleus.Plugin  - Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.core" requires "org.eclipse.text" but it cannot be resolved.
2420 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2421 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - Property javax.jdo.option.NonTransactionalRead unknown - will be ignored
2421 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - ================= Persistence Configuration ===============
2426 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "2.0.3"
2426 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - DataNucleus Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true" driver="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" userName="APP"
2426 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - ===========================================================
8704 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema  - Initialising Catalog "", Schema "APP" using "None" auto-start option
8704 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Datastore.Schema  - Catalog "", Schema "APP" initialised - managing 0 classes
8795 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore  - Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
8832 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.MetaData  - Registering listener for metadata initialisation
8858 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore  - Initialized ObjectStore

Am not sure why the Oozie is not reading the User defined "hive-default.xml" and the same is reading from Some Jar, not sure which Jar its being used.
Also why/how every 1st Run of the fresh Oozie job getting success where from the second run onwards the job is not able to read the same.
Could you guys help me find out where am missing or what need to be update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue got resolved once placed the OJDBC Driver in the shared Lib location of HDFS.

The said Jar was not available in Oozie Shared Location, where as Derby Jar was available, so Oozie was trying to connect the Derby for Hive-MetaStore. in default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert just above the `<configuration>` tag:

```
<job-xml>[HIVE SETTINGS FILE]</job-xml>
```

where `[HIVE SETTINGS FILE]` is the file most commonly called `hive-site.xml`. This will enable your Hive script to connect to the metastore.

Comment: Missed to mention, have tried with the job-xml parameter as well, but the same got failed with exception like "JA010: Property [mapred.job.tracker] not allowed in action [job-xml] configuration". Anycorrection required in workflow???

Comment: Have found one more mismatch,where I have set variables like datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=false
datanucleus.autoCreateTables=true
datanucleus.fixedDatastore=true
which is being checked by the Hive action on the 1st run, but on the second run the same is not being checked